# Distribute dates as per equipment's maintenance frequency with criteria

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary

Guys I need your assistance on how to develop a code to distribute dates as per maintenance frequency of equipment.
Each equipment has a proper plan with a defined frequency.

- Day(s)
- Week(s)
- Month(s)

To have a good overview I would like to see the behaviour of the plans along a period (5 years) considering the frequency of each equipment's maintenance plan.
I have a list of some equipment that I want to fix their maintenance plan starting date. Meaning that they will have some maintenance starting together based on their frequency.
I have 2 worksheets (General Plans) and (StartingReference).

StartingReference has a table like this:

```
+-------------+-----------+
| Equipment   | Starts on |
+=============+===========+
| Equipment A | 1/13/2020 |
+-------------+-----------+
| Equipment B | 1/13/2020 |
+-------------+-----------+
| Equipment C | 2/28/2020 |
+-------------+-----------+
| Equipment D | 2/28/2020 |
+-------------+-----------+
```

I need a code that can read the date & frequency on columns D & E and mark "x" on column that will be the next due date. Check the date on Column E and add the "X" on the respective date as per row#1 that contains all my period of 5 years - **Each column has a specific date**. 
Before start to distribute the dates based on frequency column, the code will check if that Equipment have some specific date defined on StartingReference sheet.

My sheet General Plans has the following structure.

```
+-------------+-----------------+------------------+------------+---------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| Equipment   | Discipline      | Maintenance Type | Frequency  | Next Due date | 01/01 | 01/02 | (...) | 01/08 | 01/09 | (...) | 01/13 | (...) | 02/01 | (...) | 02/28 | (...) | 04/01 | (...) |
+=============+=================+==================+============+===============+=======+=======+=======+=======+=======+=======+=======+=======+=======+=======+=======+=======+=======+=======+
| Equipment A | Mechanical      | A                | 1 Week(s)  | 1/1/2020      | x     |       |       | x     |       |       | x     |       |       |       |       |       |       |       |
+-------------+-----------------+------------------+------------+---------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| Equipment A | Instrumentation | B                | 1 Month(s) | 1/1/2020      | x     |       |       |       |       |       | x     |       | x     |       |       |       |       |       |
+-------------+-----------------+------------------+------------+---------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| Equipment C | Electrical      | C                | 3 Month(s) | 1/1/2020      | x     |       |       |       |       |       |       |       |       |       |       |       | x     |       |
+-------------+-----------------+------------------+------------+---------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| Equipment B | Instrumentation | B                | 1 Month(s) | 2/28/2020     |       |       |       |       |       |       | X     |       |       |       | x     |       |       |       |
+-------------+-----------------+------------------+------------+---------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

I start to write some code but I need to confess - I got lost...

```
Option Explicit
Sub DistributeMaintenancePlans()
Dim Dict As Object, CriteriaInterval As Range


With SetUp.Range("A2").CurrentRegion
    Set CriteriaInterval = .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count) 'No Headers
End With

Dim EquipCriteria As Range
Set Dict = New Scripting.Dictionary

For Each EquipCriteria In CriteriaInterval
    Dict(EquipCriteria.Value) = EquipCriteria.Offset(, 1).Value
Next
'Loop
Dim Arr() As Variant

With Sheet2.Range("A2").CurrentRegion
    Arr = .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count) 'No Headers
End With

Dim i As Long, j As Long, tmp As Variant

Dim tmpDate As Date, lastDate As Date, tmpTxt As Variant, tdDays As Long
lastDate = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Sheets("General Plans").Range("1:1"))

For i = LBound(Arr, 1) To UBound(Arr, 1)

    tmpTxt = Split(Arr(i, 4), " ")

    Select Case tmpTxt(1)
    Case "Month(s)"
        tdDays = tmpTxt(0) * 30
    Case "Week(s)"
        tdDays = tmpTxt(0) * 7
    Case "Day(s)"
        tdDays = tmpTxt(0)
    End Select
    tmpDate = Arr(i, 1) + tdDays

    'I need to find a way to put a loop to distribute the dates here
    'tmpDate = Arr(i, 1) + tdDays


Next i

Set Dict = Nothing
Set CriteriaInterval = Nothing
```

End Sub

Comment: You probably want to use `Dict.Add "" & EquipCriteria.Value, EquipCriteria.Offset(, 1).Value` but make sure to also first check to see if it exists.

Comment: https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-dictionary/

Comment: Thank you for your feedback but there is no problem with that way I add things to the Dictionary.          Dict(EquipCriteria.Value) = EquipCriteria.Offset(, 1).Value , specially because the code already verifies if the item exists. Of course in a different way.

Answer (score 0):

I need to find a way to put a loop to distribute the dates here
tmpDate = Arr(i, 1) + tdDays

See below the code I'm trying...

```
Option Explicit
Sub DistributeMaintenancePlans()
    Dim Dict As Object, CriteriaInterval As Range


    With SetUp.Range("A2").CurrentRegion
        Set CriteriaInterval = .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count) 'No Headers
    End With

    Dim EquipCriteria As Range
    Set Dict = New Scripting.Dictionary

    For Each EquipCriteria In CriteriaInterval
        Dict(EquipCriteria.Value) = EquipCriteria.Offset(, 1).Value
    Next
    'Loop
    Dim Arr() As Variant

    With Sheet2.Range("A2").CurrentRegion
        Arr = .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count) 'No Headers
    End With

    Dim i As Long, j As Long, tmp As Variant

    Dim tmpDate As Date, lastDate As Date, tmpTxt As Variant, tdDays As Long
    lastDate = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Sheets("General Plans").Range("1:1"))

    For i = LBound(Arr, 1) To UBound(Arr, 1)

        tmpTxt = Split(Arr(i, 4), " ")

        Select Case tmpTxt(1)
        Case "Month(s)"
            tdDays = tmpTxt(0) * 30
        Case "Week(s)"
            tdDays = tmpTxt(0) * 7
        Case "Day(s)"
            tdDays = tmpTxt(0)
        End Select
        tmpDate = Arr(i, 1) + tdDays

        'I need to find a way to put a loop to distribute the dates here
        'tmpDate = Arr(i, 1) + tdDays


    Next i

    Set Dict = Nothing
    Set CriteriaInterval = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you asking another question with this answer? When you say 'I need to find a way to put a loop to distribute the dates here', are you asking how to use the dictionary method you've chosen to actually put 'x' in a cell somewhere? I don't see where your code does any 'distributing' so far...

Comment: I started to write the code - But when is necessary to distribute the dates using Dictionary I got stuck because will be required an inner loop that I dont know how to incorporate it.
Example: If the frequency is 7 days, all the weeks of a period of 5 years will receive an "x" on the row based on the Due date (Column E). I hope I could explain it

Comment: If I'm understanding so far, you already know the frequency at the 'row' loop level. I would add a loop to go through all columns, check whether the column's header (a date value) is equal to the start date plus the date frequency times some number. Something like `If (HeaderDate - StartDate) Mod tdDays = 0 Then Arr (x, y) = "x"` while looping your array's 1,830 columns - before moving onto the next row. I don't really understand the choices you've made to solve this problem so you may need to adapt this method. I believe there are simpler ways of doing what you're trying to do.

Comment: In fact this is the main idea. Looping in a period to add an "x" based on frequency. But before go looping around, will be necessary verify the starting date set on StartingReference sheet.